# Git pre-commit bash script on Windows

Tags: bash, git, githooks, pre-commit-hook

I've created a simple pre-commit script for git:

```
#!/bin/sh

if git rev-parse —verify HEAD >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    against=HEAD
else
    against=4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
fi

for FILE in `git diff --cached --name-only` ; do
    # Check if the file contains 'DbMigration'
    echo $FILE $against
    if [ -n "grep -E ':\s*DbMigration\s' $FILE" ];
    then
        echo ''
        echo ''
        echo '[**CODEPOLICE**]'
        echo '[**CODEPOLICE**]' $FILE
        echo '[**CODEPOLICE**]'
        echo '[**CODEPOLICE**] This file contains a direct subclass of DbContext! Refactor your migrations to use <...> instead!'
        echo '[**CODEPOLICE**]'
        echo ''
        echo ''
        exit 1
    fi
done

exit
```

The check `if [ -n "grep -E ':\s*DbMigration\s' $FILE" ]` fails miserably in the sense that it generates false positives.

Versions involved are:

```
Windows 10 Enterprise

$ git --version
git version 2.15.1.windows.2

$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)
```

What gives?

**Update**

Some examples:

```
 public partial class Initial : DbMigration --> we want positive & we get positive --> ok

 public partial class Initial : FoobarDbMigration --> we want negative & we get positive --> not ok

 public partial class Initial : Foobar --> we want negative & we get positive --> not ok

 public partial class Initial : DbMigrationFoobar --> we want negative & we get positive --> also not ok
```

Comment: Can you add a "positive" example and a "false positive" as well?

Comment: Thank you so much for tuning in. I will update the question per your request in a few moments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bash script that seems to fit the bill turned out to be this one:

```
#!/bin/sh

RED='\033[0;31m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color

echo ""
echo -n "[**CODEPOLICE**] Checking for usages of 'DbMigration' over 'VNextDbMigration' ... "

stagedFiles=`git diff --cached --name-only`
while read -r FILE ; do
    # Check if the file contains ': DbMigration'

    if [ -f "$FILE" ];
    then
        matchingLines=$( grep -P ":(\s|\r|\n)*DbMigration(\s|$)" "$FILE" )
        if [ "$matchingLines" != "" ];
        then
            echo -e ""
            echo -e "${RED}[**CODEPOLICE**]${NC}"
            echo -e "${RED}[**CODEPOLICE**]${NC}" $FILE
            echo -e "${RED}[**CODEPOLICE**]${NC}"
            echo -e "${RED}[**CODEPOLICE**]${NC} ^- This file contains a direct subclass of 'DbContext'! Refactor your migration to have it inherit from 'VNextDbMigration' instead!"
            echo -e "${RED}[**CODEPOLICE**]${NC}"
            echo -e ""
            echo -e ""
            exit 1
        fi
    fi
done <<< $stagedFiles

echo "ALL OK"
echo ""

exit
```

Answer (score 1):

The test

```
[ -n "grep -E ':\s*DbMigration\s' $FILE" ]
```

doesn't run the command, it tests if the string inside `""` is not empty. And it is not empty so the test always succeed!

To run the command and test its output use backticks instead of double quotes:

```
[ -n "`grep -E ':\s*DbMigration\s' $FILE`" ]
```

or use `$()`:

```
[ -n "$(grep -E ':\s*DbMigration\s' $FILE)" ]
```

Comment: Although this is a problem with the code, it does NOT give the correct result. `grep -E ':\s*DbMigration\s' $FILE | wc` will give `1 0 1` and the test for `-n` will still succeed.

Comment: @StefanM I don't know why do you talk about `wc`. And you probably need `*` at the end of re: `grep -Eq ':\s*DbMigration\s*` (looking at your examples).

Answer (score 1):

You have to start a subshell to execute the command.

To test for an empty string, you have to do it like this:

```
[ -n "$(grep -E ':\s*DbMigration\s' $FILE)" ]
```

This yields correct with all the given test cases you provided.